# Protect closed workbook with password

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched but didn't find a way to put an external password on closed workbook.
Suppose I have closed workbook named "Sample.xlm" .. and I am opening a workbook named "Test.xlm".
Is there a code that enables me to put a password on the Sample.xlsm? I mean external password ..
I tried the following but got error (method protect of object workbook failed)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.xlsm")
    wb.Protect Password:="123"
    wb.Close True
End Sub
```

** I was protecting the Sample workbook with Protect and Share Workbook and I have changed to UnShare. This was the problem of the error that appears.

Now the code is working but when opening the Sample workbook after running the code, I found it unprotected. I expect to get it protected.

** It seems I am wrong too at my approach. This would protect the structure of the workbook not to set the external password as the snapshot displays.

Thanks advanced for help

[image]

Posted here too
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/set-password-to-closed-workbook.1133150/

Comment: What do you mean by external? External from Excel? Why would it matter if you are opening test?

Comment: I need to set a password for another workbook using VBA codes.

Comment: You have to use at least one of the other two parameters. [Take a look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.protect).

Comment: I already tried this and changed `wb.Protect Password:="123", Structure:=True, Windows:=True` but the same problem. The code works but the closed workbook is not protected.

Comment: When you do it manually, you have to confirm the password i.e. enter it twice. Maybe it cannot be done? Or maybe use something like `OnKeys` or `SendKeys` (can't remember)?

Comment: I have updated the post. It seems this protection is different from what I am searching for. I am trying to Encrypt with Password as shown in the snapshot.

Comment: What does "external password" mean? Do you mean you want to be prompted for a password for just opening the file? If so then you simply can't do that off a closed workbook... the method that puts the password protection is [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) (provide a `password` argument), which implies that the workbook is opened in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I am trying to do. So there is no way to do that using VBA.?

Comment: There is - `book.SaveAs FileName:=path, Password:="P@$$w0rd"`, the thing you *cannot* do is put a password on a workbook for which you don't have a `Workbook` object reference, i.e. a workbook that isn't opened.

Comment: The password protection is implemented through `Workbook.SaveAs` - the limitation isn't VBA, it's just how the Excel object library exposes its functionality... pretty sure this means you couldn't password-protect a closed workbook in C++ either. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much, That solved the problem `wb.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NewSample.xlsm", Password:="123"`. Kind Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) - one of the optional parameters, `Password`, will do what you're after... but you need to open the workbook first - and as with any code dealing with the file system, we need to handle errors here:

```
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim path As String
    path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.xlsm"
    With Workbooks.Open(path)
        .SaveAs path, Password:="P@$$w0rd"
        .Close
    End With
CleanExit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's great. Question please: Is it possible to put a code in the protected file in `Workbook_BeforeSave` event that re-encrypts the file in case the user can save the file with another name. The idea is that the protected workbook will be used by many users and they will have the password, but I would like to prevent them from changing the password at the same time. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Cancel the save and save on your own terms =)

Comment: I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: The BeforeSave handler should have a ByRef Cancel parameter: have a `Private Saving As Boolean` module-level flag, and in the handler you can do `If Saving Then Saving = False / Exit Sub / End If` then `Saving = True / Cancel = True`, and then the `SaveAs` with the password... but then if the user isn't providing the password you end up with the password in the code - best leave the user in charge of this. Cheers!

Comment: (you could use an `InputBox` to get the password from the user, and cancel everything if the password prompt is cancelled)

Comment: To be honest. I am lost. The user will know the password but at the same time I need to prevent him from changing the password. Complicated.

Comment: The point is to get the password concern completely out of the code, so that it doesn't matter what the password is: if you prompt the user for the password before you programmatically open, and prompt for the password before you programmatically save, then I don't see why the code needs to have the password hard-coded anywhere, or why users can't manage their passwords - a side-effect of this is that the workbook becomes unusable when they forget the password, ...because a secure file is, well, secure; I'd keep a local unprotected "recovery" copy of the file in case that happens.

Comment: Can you show me with code please how to do that programmatically in Save event as I tried but I got the file corrupted and excel hanged. Thanks a lot for your awesome help.

Comment: Consider asking a new question, this is getting complicated :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61636400/