# Set password for open by VBA instead of built-in feature

Tags: excel, vba

I have a previous topic about setting password for another workbook. The other workbook is named "Sample.xlsm"
[Protect closed workbook with password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624393/)

Now I need to make the user input the password from the Sample.xlsm itself and at the same time to prevent the user from changing the password

I used this

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If SaveAsUI Then MsgBox "SaveAs Feature Disabled", vbExclamation: Cancel = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But this seems not enough from preventing the user to save the workbook with another name.

Comment: Don't see any problem with your code (other than you don't need `Application.DisplayAlerts`). What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Your `BeforeSave` event should essentially start with `Cancel = True` and `SaveAsUI = False`.   This will prevent the expected save functionality from occurring.  You can use an if-statement, but I would recommend doing it based on a "check" if the `SaveAsUI` existed (which should already have been set to `False` to perform actions.  See the [documentation for `BeforeSave`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force only saving to a specific location:

This is the code that should stop most attempts at saving:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cancel = True
    Call MySaveCode
BackToExcelSave:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then you have to add code for your save, and avoid triggering excels' default save routine:

```
Sub MySaveCode()

    On Error GoTo ReEnable ' Use On Error in case they cannot save to specified location/filename
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' turn off excel default action (Workbook_BeforeSave)
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Path = "C:\Users\SeanC\Documents\Excel\"

    FileName = "MyFixedFilename.xlsm"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False    'Optional. Suppresses default excel messages

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            Path & FileName, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
            CreateBackup:=False, _
            Password:="P@$$w0rd"

    MsgBox "Saved as: " & ThisWorkbook.FullName 'Also Optional

ReEnable:
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True    'Optional
     Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: he is not using `Cancel=True` to cancel out of the save.

Comment: @BigBen, Fixed.

Comment: I need to allow Save process but to prevent SaveAs. will this do that? And I already used Cancel=True after the message box.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. This prevents SaveAs at last. and at the sane time allows save. Thanks a lot for this great solution.

Comment: Is it possible to add the password parameter to encrypt the file or this is not possible ..?

Comment: Anything you can do with SaveAs or Protect, you can do in the save routine

Comment: Your code is perfect for my needs. I need a powerful protection. Before setting the password I can encrypt the VBE using a tool named `EvilClippy`. it is simple tool. But the problem is that after setting a password I can't use the tool to encrypt the workbook. I hope to find a workaround that enables me to set encryption for a protected workbook (encrypted with password I mean)

Comment: If the macro is disabled, the user will be able to use F12 . Is there a way to disable F12 without the using of codes..? I am stuck at this point and didn't find any solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing can be done if macros are disabled. You could try code signing to get Excel to trust the code and run it without prompting to enable macros, but it will cost to get a code signing certificate

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me details about "code signing certificate"?How can I do that? Is this will be available on any PC? How much does it cost?

Comment: from one company that supplies the certificate: https://www.globalsign.com/en/code-signing-certificate/what-is-code-signing-certificate  They cost (from) $289 per year, depending on validation length and options requested. Search for Code Signing Certificate, and you will find various companies and prices.